# Blank Plot Output when using "geom_xspline" in ggalt package

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline, ggpubr, ggalt

When trying to use `geom_xspline` from `ggalt` in conjunction with `ggarrange` from `ggpubr`, the output is blank and no other plot can be made before clearing with `dev.off()`.

In my use-case I wanted the `geom_xspline` to replace some exisitng `geom_line` in my ggplot object. Is anyone aware of issues using geoms added from other R packages?

Here is some code to compare, nothing of interest really, just to give a reproducible example:

**Initial Working Code w/o `geom_xspline`**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
myplot = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
geom_line()
ggarrange(myplot, myplot) # Works and outputs fine
```

**Code that fails with `ggalt` package**

```r
library(ggalt)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
myplot = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
geom_xspline()
ggarrange(myplot, myplot) # Output becomes blank and freezes the plot panel
```

**Alternative Method**
Instead of using `ggarrange` I tried the function `grid_arrange_shared_legend` from this [link](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs), which uses `grid` and `gridExtra`. However, I am still curious as to why `ggarrange` does not work.

**Here is my session info:**

```r
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggpubr_0.1.8  magrittr_1.5  ggplot2_3.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18       pillar_1.3.0       compiler_3.5.1     RColorBrewer_1.1-2 plyr_1.8.4         bindr_0.1.1       
 [7] tools_3.5.1        extrafont_0.17     tibble_1.4.2       gtable_0.2.0       pkgconfig_2.0.1    rlang_0.2.1       
[13] rstudioapi_0.7     yaml_2.2.0         bindrcpp_0.2.2     Rttf2pt1_1.3.7     withr_2.1.2        dplyr_0.7.6       
[19] maps_3.3.0         grid_3.5.1         ggalt_0.4.0        tidyselect_0.2.4   cowplot_0.9.3      glue_1.3.0        
[25] R6_2.2.2           purrr_0.2.5        extrafontdb_1.0    scales_1.0.0       MASS_7.3-50        assertthat_0.2.0  
[31] proj4_1.0-8        colorspace_1.3-2   labeling_0.3       KernSmooth_2.23-15 ash_1.0-15         lazyeval_0.2.1    
[37] munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Quick addition, if I convert the object to a `ggplotGrob()`, it will work with `ggarrange`, but it will fail when I attempt to use `common.legend = T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xspline` function, upon which`geom_xspline` is based, typically automatically plots using `graphics`. This led the `ggalt` package authors to find a few work-arounds to ensure it would play nicely with `ggplot`.  My rough solutions both involve creating or adjusting a `geom` or `stat` from `ggplot` without using `xspline`. This makes it easier to use without a lot of pre-processing the data prior to ingesting with `ggplot`.

**(1) New `stat` using `splines`**

Using `spline` for interpolation of points instead of `xspline`.

```r
# Create a new stat (adjusted from ggalt GitHub page)
stat_spline <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "line",
                         position = "identity", na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
                         n=200, method = "fmm", ...) { # Just picking a rough default for n
  layer(
    stat = StatSpline,
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    geom = geom,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(n=n,
                  method=method,
                  na.rm = na.rm,
                  ...
    )
  )
}

StatSpline <- ggproto("StatSpline", Stat,

                       required_aes = c("x", "y"),

                       compute_group = function(self, data, scales, params,
                                                n=200, method = "fmm") {

                         tmp <- spline(data$x, data$y, n = n, method = method, ties = mean)

                         data.frame(x=tmp$x, y=tmp$y)
                       }

)

# Plot with ggarrange
myplot = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
stat_spline(mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
geom_point()

ggpubr::ggarrange(myplot, myplot)
```

This method isn't ideal if you want splines similar to Catmull-Rom instead of Cubic; you can see some large bends between control points.

[image]

**(2) New `geom` using `xsplineGrob`**

This is a slightly adjusted version of `geom_xspline2` from `ggalt`

```r
# Create new geom based upon code from ggalt GitHub page
GeomXSpline3 <- ggproto("GeomXSpline3", Geom,
                        required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                        default_aes = aes(colour = "black", shape=-1, open=T),
                        draw_key = draw_key_point,

                        draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord) {
                          coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
                          grid::xsplineGrob(
                            coords$x, coords$y,
                            shape = coords$shape, 
                            open = coords$open[1],
                            gp = grid::gpar(col = coords$colour)
                          )
                        }
)

geom_xspline3 <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
                          position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                          inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    geom = GeomXSpline3, mapping = mapping,  data = data, stat = stat,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

# Plot with ggarrange
myplot = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_xspline3(shape = -.25) + geom_point()
ggpubr::ggarrange(myplot, myplot)
```

There were a couple issues with ensuring the shape parameter still accepted inputs between -1 and 1, however, this seems to be working okay now with `ggarrange`.

[image]

I used the following resources while writing this solution:

- A [blog](https://rud.is/b/2015/09/08/roll-your-own-stats-and-geoms-in-ggplot2-part-1-splines/) post from an author from `ggalt`
- The GitHub page for [`geom_xspline`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt/blob/master/R/geom_xspline.r) and [`geom_xspline2`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt/blob/master/R/geom_xspline2.r)
- ggplot [vignette](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/extending-ggplot2.html) on extending ggplot

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not sure why `ggpubr::ggarrange` causes failure of Plots pannel when used with `ggalt::geom_xspline` but I can tell you that plots are still getting created but just now shown on the plot pannel.

So it seems that using those together causes failure in the graphing device and it is only happening for `ggalt::geom_xspline` and not all the `geoms` in [ggalt](/questions/tagged/ggalt). That is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) so you are on the right track posting to [GitHub](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/131).

You can check that by running the code below:

```r
library(ggalt)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


myplot = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_xspline()
myplot
```

[image]

```r
g <- ggarrange(myplot, myplot) # Output becomes blank and freezes the plot panel
g

jpeg('rplot.jpg')
g
dev.off()
#> pdf 
#>   3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

And this is the saved plot:

[image]

Comment: That plot looks incredibly strange compared to a normal line plot. I also noticed some strange artifacts appear when using `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`. Any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: @Klink it's not a line plot. Would you post another question, explaining what exactly you mean by strange? You can ping me here and link to that question and I'll take a look. Thanks.